# Get the Product URL in the Custom Module Controller File

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, error, product-images, adminform

I'm using this in my controller file to get the current product URL and insert it into database.

Tried this solution, but it works partially: instead of ***http://formodulecheck.dev/media/catalog/product/p/r/product.jpg*** it's returning ***http://formodulecheck.dev/index.php/catalog/product/view/***

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
$productUrl = $product->getProductUrl();
```

**Version 2** - Also tried this:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id); 
$product_url=Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'thumbnail');
echo $product_url." HERE IS THE PRODUCT URL";
```

And getting this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getData() on null in app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Helper\Image.php on line 166

How can I fix this?
(Thanks for the help)

Comment: Can you please add your full form code? what is the value for `$_product` in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending hours and trying dozens of possible solutions, I found one that worked for me [in this tiny article](http://www.blog.plazathemes.com/archives/2300).

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$productMediaConfig = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config');
$productUrl = $productMediaConfig->getMediaUrl($product->getThumbnail());

$connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$connectionWrite = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_write');
$table = 'cpstest_productcomment_cps';
$data = array(
    'id' => NULL,
    'productcomment_increment_id' => $product_id,
    'customer_email' => $user_email,
    'name'    =>  $user_name,
    'comment_status' => 'Not Approved',
    'comment_date' => $comment_date,
    'comment_txt' => $user_comment_notags,
    'product_name' => $product_name,
    'product_image_url'=>$productUrl,
    );
```

Hopefully someone will save time on this.

Comment: how to get product complete url in custom module observer